# How to get the coordinates to display a pin on Mapkit Swift

Tags: swift, geolocation, mapkit

Hi how can I transform my `address` into coordinates (longitude and latitude) using the geocoder in swift ? I want to be able to pin the location of an address which is saved in a variable.

```
let address = GlobalVariable.eventClicked.address
@IBOutlet var EventsMapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.EventsMapView.delegate = self
    }
```

I'm using this code to get the coordinates but i'm not able to save it outside this completion blocks, I'm new in swift.

```
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, err) in
        guard err == nil,
            let allPlacemarks = placemarks,
            let place = allPlacemarks.first,
            let loc = place.location else {
                return
            }
        print("log \(loc.coordinate)")
}
```

So my question is how can i save the coordinates and then add a pin on the map ? Thanks